# displaying/removing a certain text automatically

Tags: php

Sorry to ask such a stupid question. I'm a newbie.
Is it possible to display the email link on my website only at a certain time and remove it for the rest of the day automatically? Thanks a lot for any help..

#### Update:

Any idea why this code doesn't work?

```
<?php
   if( date('Gi', time()) >= 1400 && date('Gi', time()) <= 1600 )
   {
         print "<a href="http://www.examplelink.com">Click here!</a>";
   }
?>
```

Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but we'll need more details before being able to provide specific help.  Provide the php, database, html, javascript related code you are working with.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all you need is something like the following that uses PHPs date() functions:

```
if (date('G') = 17)
{
  ...code to display email address...
  ...this will only happen between 17:00 and 17.59
}
```

You can play around with the if to use different conditions.  Have a look at the PHP date page for other possible usages:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

One thing to keep in mind here is that this uses the datetime on the server not the user viewing the site.

Answer (score 1):

Get the time using `Date()` and then use a conditional to print your link:

```
# Get the time
var now = new Date();
var hrs = now.getHours();

# Only print the link if it's between 9am and 5pm
if (hrs > 9 && hrs <17) {
     print '<a href="http://www.examplelink.com">Click here!</a>'; 
}
```